# How to include given mode in index.js

Tags: node.js

I have this given module in config.js. I want to include this is my index.js. I tried multiple ways but config variable is always undefined.
I tried like this.

```
const config = require('./config') //undefined
const config = require('./config')("dev") //error
const config = require('./config')["dev"] // error
const config = require('./config').get("dev")
```

Here is how i run it

```
// my command.
 npm run start:dev

"scripts": {
    "start:prod": "set NODE_ENV=prod pm2 start index.js --watch",
    "start:dev": "set NODE_ENV=dev && node index.js"
  },
```

Here is module

```
let env = process.env.NODE_ENV; 
require('dotenv').config();
const dev = {
    app: {
        port: parseInt(process.env.DEV_APP_PORT) || 3000
    },
    db: {
        host: process.env.DEV_DB_HOST || 'localhost',
        port: parseInt(process.env.DEV_DB_PORT) || 27017,
        name: process.env.DEV_DB_NAME || 'myDB',

    },
    imagePath: "./profileImages/",
    LogFillePath: "logs/combined.log",
    ErrorFilePaht: "logs/error.log",
    JwtSecret: process.env.JWT_SECRET
};
const prod = {
    app: {
        port: parseInt(process.env.PROD_APP_PORT) || 9000
    },
    db: {
        host: process.env.PROD_DB_HOST || 'localhost',
        port: parseInt(process.env.PROD_DB_PORT) || 27017,
        name: process.env.PROD_DB_NAME || 'myDB'
    },
    imagePath: "./profileImages/",
    LogFillePath: "logs/combined.log",
    ErrorFilePaht: "logs/error.log",
    JwtSecret: process.env.JWT_SECRET
};

const config = {
    dev,
    prod
};

module.exports = config[env];
```

I have this given module in config.js. I want to include this is my index.js. I tried multiple ways but config variable is always undefined.
I tried like this.

Comment: try it without spaces `set NODE_ENV=dev&&node index.js`, i tried your code mac and its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this for your `config.js`:

```
require("dotenv").config();

const dev = {
  // ...
};
const prod = {
  // ...
};

const configs = {
  dev,
  prod,
};

const config = configs[process.env.NODE_ENV];

if (!config) throw new Error("No valid configuration found, ensure your NODE_ENV is properly set");

module.exports = config;
```

Then you can simply

```
const config = require('./config');
```

Comment: config is still undefined with error  "No valid configuration found, ensure your NODE_ENV is properly set"
although i have console.info printing that env is dev at top of config.js file.

Comment: If you add `NODE_ENV=dev` into your `.env` file?

Comment: Thanks i figured it out, there was space in script between dev and &&
    "start:dev": "set NODE_ENV=dev && node index.js"